# Creating a Div inside an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to create a div inside an iframe in HTML.

When I load the page the div does not show up.

```
<iframe id="frame">
<html>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">hi</div>    
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

IN HTML5 you can do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe srcdoc="<div id='mydiv'>hi</div>" src="demo_iframe_srcdoc.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

W3C Documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3Y7J/